# Why is the "run as administrator" option greyed out?

Tags: windows-7

Have a .bat file which needs to run as Administrator, but the option under properties is greyed out.  Why is that when I have local admin rights on the computer?

Comment: Are there any other file types that are doing the same thing?  What version of windows are you using (ex: win vista home)

Comment: @Codezilla - It says its Windows 7.

Comment: does the .bat run fine? Do you have User Account Control (UAC) turned off?

Answer (score 1):

## Problem

I think there are different techniques involved when running stuff as admin.
For applications, there is the compatibility tab. Those settings are stored in the registry. You will probably see some applications listed on your machine:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Compatibility Assistant\Persisted
```

A batch or cmd file is not an application. It's a script run by the application cmd.exe. Thus it is not handled by the application compatibility settings in the registry.

Further the batch-file has no way to store the information, that it should be run as admin.

## Solution

But there's another way to do it:

1. create a shortcut (link) to the cmd/bat file.
2. in the shortcut properties, on the Shortcut tab, click the *Advanced ...* button
3. check the *run as Administrator* checkbox.

Note that even in the shortcut properties, the *run as administrator* is grayed out on the *compatibility* tab. The runas-option is stored in the shortcut (.lnk) file.

## On a side note

You could actually set the grayed out run as admin checkbox in the registry:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Layers
```

Create a REG_SZ key with the full path to your batch file and "RUNASADMIN" as value. (... or probably easier: check the 256 color option in the properties and edit the registry entry.)  **But this won't work.** At least not for most files. That's probably why it was grayed out on the compatibility tab in the first place.

Anyway that's just what I deduced for me. I found no official documentation on this.

Answer (score -1):

worse case scenario you could load cmd as administrator then run the bat.